# How to get custom fileds' value when I request posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

In wordpress，I add **different custom filed** in **different posts**. When I request posts (/wp-json/wp/v2/posts) , there is no custom field value What should I do to get the custom fields？

Comment: there is a method to add custom fields to apis, for the rest api can use advance custom fields extension to  advance custom fields plugin

Comment: The REST API doesn't provide custom fields by default. However, you can add them to your site by modifying responses. Check this: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/

Answer (score 0):

You should try this!

```
  <?php 
       $custom_fields = get_post_custom(72);
       $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['my_custom_field'];
       foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ) {
          echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
       } 
?>
```

OR for more reference : you can visit the https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Thanks,
Jenish.